# libstdc++ - not linking statically using qmake

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, g++, static-linking

I compile a dynamic and static version of my library on Debian 7. My user wants to use the library on RHEL6, so after reading many posts it seemed linking libstdc++ statically should fix the issue.

I am using `qmake`, so in the `.pro` file I added

```
unix: QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -fvisibility=hidden -w
```

Then I execute following command:

```
qmake MyLibrary.pro -spec linux-g++-64 "CONFIG += release"
```

and the output is

```
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -O2 -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -fvisibility=hidden -w -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DMYLIBRARY_LIBRARY -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4 -IMyLibrary/Curl/include -I. -o LexAbstraction.o MyLibrary/LexAbstraction.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -O2 -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -fvisibility=hidden -w -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DMYLIBRARY_LIBRARY -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4 -IMyLibrary/Curl/include -I. -o MyLibrary.o MyLibrary/MyLibrary.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -O2 -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -fvisibility=hidden -w -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DMYLIBRARY_LIBRARY -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4 -IMyLibrary/Curl/include -I. -o LexBotan.o MyLibrary/LexBotan.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -O2 -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -fvisibility=hidden -w -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DMYLIBRARY_LIBRARY -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4 -IMyLibrary/Curl/include -I. -o LexCrypter.o MyLibrary/LexCrypter.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -O2 -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -fvisibility=hidden -w -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DMYLIBRARY_LIBRARY -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4 -IMyLibrary/Curl/include -I. -o LexHelper.o MyLibrary/LexHelper.cpp
rm -f libMyLibrary.so
g++ -m64 -Wl,-O1 -shared -o libMyLibrary.so LexAbstraction.o MyLibrary.o LexBotan.o LexCrypter.o LexHelper.o   -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lpthread
```

But when I execute

```
ldd -v libMyLibrary.so | grep GLIBCXX
```

It gives following output:

```
libstdc++.so.6 (GLIBCXX_3.4.15) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
libstdc++.so.6 (GLIBCXX_3.4.9) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
libstdc++.so.6 (GLIBCXX_3.4) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
```

Comment: You ever figure this out? I've run into the same issues, even with correct options passed to linker? It compiles, but when run it's still looking at the libstdc++ that's in the path instead of the statically linked one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-static-libstdc++` and `-static-libgcc` are linkage options, but you are
passing them for compilation (where they are ignored) and not for linkage.

C++ compile options go in `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_{RELEASE|DEBUG}`. Linkage
options go in `QMAKE_LFLAGS_{RELEASE|DEBUG}`.

`-fvisibility` is a compile option, so it should remain in `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE`

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it's giving an error: /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/libstdc++.a(compatibility.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `_ZTIN10__cxxabiv115__forced_unwindE' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/libstdc++.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @adnankamili As the diagnostic suggests, you need to compile objects with the option `-fPIC` if you mean to link them in a shared library.